# qt's QSettings to access the SharedPreferences in android

Tags: android, c++, qt, sharedpreferences, qsettings

In Qt (5.3)+Android, does anyone know the way to access the values in the Android's SharedPreferences with qt's QSettings?

I've tried several combinations of QSettings but they don't seem to catch the right one. The might be a QSettings specifiying the filepath but it does not seem too clear where it is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different things and it is currently not possible to access or write Android Shared Preferences via QSettings. There might be some integration in the future, or at least some QtAndroidExtras addition, but as of writing this (Qt 5.3.1), it is not there.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it isnt there (if it is it's quite elusive). I was looking for it in order to access the Preferences (Settings). I am thinking on keeping a private QSettings automatically tracking the onSharedPreferenceChanged (java)

Comment: It's possible using JNI.